# Drupal 8 migrate fields not filled

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to migrate content to D8 site from sql source. In my migrate_plus.migration.node_article.yml config file I've following:

```
id: node_article
label: Article Migration
migration_group: node_migration
source:
  plugin: node_article
  bundle: node
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
process:
  uuid: uuid
  title: title
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
  field_seo_title: title
  field_teaser_text: title
migration_dependencies: {}
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - my_article_import
```

(field_seo_title is a textfield)
and NodeArticle.php:

```
class NodeArticle extends SqlBase
{

    public function query()
    {

        //query code ommited
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        $fields = [
            'uuid' => $this->t('Unique Unique Identifier'),
            'title' => $this->t('Title'),
            'field_teaser_text_value' => $this->t('field_teaser_text_value'),
            'field_seo_title_value' => $this->t('field_seo_title_value'),
        ];

        return $fields;
    }

    public function prepareRow(Row $row)
    {
        return parent::prepareRow($row);
    }

    public function getIds()
    {
        return [
            'nid' => [
                'type' => 'integer',
                'alias' => 'n',
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

When I run migration, node is created, title get filled but all other fields are empty no matter what data I try to import. I spent almost a day trying to figure out why but running out of ideas. Does anyone have an idea what could be an issue please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a complete example for you migration?

Comment: Also will be useful a dump of a row being migrated, you can get it if you add a breakpoint in `core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php:203`

Comment: ok, added complete yml config file and NodeArticle plugin. A screenshot of $row from MigrateExecutable::import:203:
https://www.screencast.com/t/5IarMfH4WAr

Comment: From the above screenshot, a node got created with title 'Milování „pod obojí“' but field_seo_title and field_teaser_text are emty.

Comment: I don't see anyting wrong in your YAML (perhaps the "bundle" under source, but I'm sure is a custom key). But caught my eye that the screenshot is showing that the destination has "nid" set, where did you get this? I mean on MigrateExecutable the entity is no saved yet, so no nid should be present there. Also can you implement `hook_node_presave` and make sure that just before saving the node everything is properly set?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe try mapping into an array rather than a single value. I look at some of the drupal field migration plugins, which, apart from the base class, are processing both value and format (in particular [TextField::defineValueProcessPipeline](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21text%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21field%21d6%21TextField.php/function/TextField%3A%3AdefineValueProcessPipeline/8.8.x)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source class works, there are two things I'm spotting:

A)
Do not prefill internal entity keys like `nid`, `uuid` or `revision_id` in the migration YML, the Migrate module will set them for you. Manually setting them is not required at best, and a potential cause of errors at worst.

B)
If your text fields are plain text fields, then your YML should be correct. But if your text fields are formatted text fields, then you also have to fill the  `format` sub column for those text fields:

```
  process:
    ...
    field_formattedtext/value: source_field
    field_formattedtext/format:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: my_format_eg_basic_html
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Point A was a good hint - I removed all the extra keys and it started to work. The problematic was however 'langcode' key which i forgot to add to the above code. 
The keys nid, uuid and revision_id were pertty much leftovers but I think the reason for those  was to keep the content as similar as possible to the original site. Not sure if it's a good idea to manually set nid to keep it the same though, I'll most likely remove it and leave it up to Drupal and migrate process to handle them.

Comment: Migrating the UUID should not be a problem (I've done it myself) but you never should try to migrate revisions neither database identifiers such 'nid'.